# Can I set different fill color based on a given threshold in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to have different fill colors for values above or below a given threshold in Chart.js ([Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/))?

I can't find any option to do this in Chart.js, has anyone done something like this before? I prefer to use Chart.js over Highcharts.

Like this: [Highcharts example](http://jsfiddle.net/cdty408f/)

html

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '$'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Win/Loss'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Avg. ($)',
            data: [546, 342, -234, -540, 103, -345],
            threshold: -1,
            negativeFillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
            fillColor: 'rgba(0,204,0,0.5)',
            lineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                lineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },{
            name: 'User ($)',
            data: [-640, -665, -700, -640, -630, -623],
            fillOpacity: 0,
            lineColor: 'rgba(20, 94, 204, 1)',
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                lineColor: 'rgba(20, 94, 204, 1)',
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to change the color of the y-axis labels, so that all positive values have a green color and all negative values have a red color?

Comment: This answer can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/31268108/9695286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a similar thing using gradientStroke command, then applying this to the backgroundColor:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("YearsExperience").getContext("2d");
var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 1200, 0, 0);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#80b6f4");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.2, "#94d973");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, "#80b6f4");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "#94d973");
var YearsExperience = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: { labels: ArrLabel[idx], datasets: [{ label: 'Years of experience', data: ArrData[idx], backgroundColor: gradientStroke }] },
    options: { scales: { xAxes: [{gridLines: {display:false}}], yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero:true } }] }, events: ['none'],animation: { easing: "easeInOutBack" } }
    });
```

An example of the output can be seen here: http://neophytte.mine.nu/portfolio/skills.html

Comment: This could work if one can set the gradient to do a hard switch at the 0 value. The idea looks similar to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916867/chart-js-line-different-fill-color-for-negative-point or this solution https://jsfiddle.net/c1w5Laee/