# chart.js Line chart with different background colors for each section

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Lets say I have a Line chart with mon-fri for 4 weeks.
I want that these 4 weeks are diveded in sections. I want the first monday to friday have a white background color.
The second monday to friday a gray background.
The thirth a white bg again.
And the fourth weeks with monday to friday to have a gray background color.
What Im talking about is the background of the graph.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chart.js clears the canvas before drawing (or redrawing) a chart.

We can jump in on this and draw our background once the chart is cleared. Just extend the Line chart and override the clear function in the initialize override.

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function(data){
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        // keep a reference to the original clear
        this.originalClear = this.clear;
        this.clear = function () {

            this.originalClear();

            // 1 x scale unit
            var unitX = this.datasets[0].points[1].x - this.datasets[0].points[0].x;

            var yTop = this.scale.startPoint;
            var yHeight = this.scale.endPoint - this.scale.startPoint;

            // change your color here
            this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(100,100,100,0.8)';

            // we shift it by half a x scale unit to the left because the space between gridline is actually a shared space
            this.chart.ctx.fillRect(this.datasets[0].points[5].x - 0.5 * unitX, yTop, unitX * 5, yHeight);
            this.chart.ctx.fillRect(this.datasets[0].points[15].x - 0.5 * unitX, yTop, unitX * 5, yHeight);
        }
    }
});
```

Then just use LineAlt instead of Line

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/oe2606ww/

Comment: Have you migrate your solution to v2 ? because the jsddifle doesn't work on the chartjs v2.

Comment: @Yvan See my answer below which is compatible with 2.9.3

Answer (score 6):

Some people here have requested something that works for later versions, here's my hacked together solution that works on ChartJS 2.7.2 **(EDIT: Apr 2020: Also 2.9.3)** and could probably be adapted.  `Chart.types.Line.extend` used in the answer above, doesn't seem to be valid in v2.

[image: graph with background relvant to x]

I managed to figure this out with help from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38493678/2052575) to get the plugin code, and also found [this thread](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2447) useful for gathering co-ordinates of the data points.

With some work this fiddle should allow you to pass the label array keys as start/stop positions via the following code (where 0 and 1 are the keys):

```
var start = meta.data[0]._model.x;
var stop  = meta.data[1]._model.x;
```

You could loop this, along with the `ctx.fillRect` function to draw multiple rectangles.

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oe2606ww/436/

Answer (score 2):

I combined @potatopeelings's and @v25's solutions for a chart.js v2 solution.  It utilizes the format of @potatopeelings's solution, allowing to use an alternate chart type (LineAlt), and the updated implementation from @v25's solution.

```
Chart.controllers.LineAlt = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    draw: function (ease) {
        if (this.chart.config.options.chartArea && this.chart.config.options.chartArea.backgroundColor) {
            var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
            var chartArea = this.chart.chartArea;

            var meta = this.chart.getDatasetMeta(0);

            var start = meta.data[1]._model.x;
            var stop  = meta.data[2]._model.x;

            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle = this.chart.config.options.chartArea.backgroundColor;
            ctx.fillRect(start, chartArea.top, stop - start, chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top);
            ctx.restore();
        }

        // Perform regular chart draw
        Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
    }
});
```

Then you can use the custom chart type just as in @potatopeelings's solution:

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {type: 'LineAlt', data: data});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a little work around,I'd draw an image with four line each one with width 1px and a different color; then in a CSS sheet define:

```
canvas {
    background-image: url(backgroundimage.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. But the left axis will also be covered by bg image. There would need to begin drawing bg-image after the left axis. But the width of that axis has variable length.