# Chart JS Chart Background Pattern

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts

I have checked out the chart js [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/canvas-background.html)

Also this post: [Chart area background color chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493564/chart-area-background-color-chartjs?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top) , and others

But I have not been able to find a way to create a horizontally striped background of the plotting area with two rgba colors.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks!

- this is for an application built using the angular framework