# Chartjs different row background colors according to Y axis values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I add multiple colors for chartjs background? I have already added single color but what I want just like following image
[image]

this is my code

```
chartArea: {
          backgroundColor:'rgba(251, 85, 85, 0.2)',
        }
```

I used plugin service as follow

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDraw: function (chart, easing) {
        if (chart.config.options.chartArea && chart.config.options.chartArea.backgroundColor) {
            var helpers = Chart.helpers;
            var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            var chartArea = chart.chartArea;

            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle = chart.config.options.chartArea.backgroundColor;
            ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, chartArea.top, chartArea.right - chartArea.left, chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Something like a gradient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chart.js Line chart with different background colors for each section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244698/chart-js-line-chart-with-different-background-colors-for-each-section)

Comment: I want add row colors not column colors

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the box annotations feature of chartjs-plugin-annotation. 
https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation