# chartjs conditional formatting for line and area

Tags: chart.js

is there a way for chartjs to do conditional formatting for it's line and area fill charts? basically if values are above a certain threshold, turn the line color to red(or another) vs a different color when values are bellow the given threshold. after looking around I found that AmCharts which does [exactly that](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-line-chart/?theme=material). Problem is I already have so many charts in my project done using chartjs am wondering if there could be a way of doing it in chartjs as well, rather than have AmCharts as additional resource to load.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: solved. it was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916867/chart-js-line-different-fill-color-for-negative-point)